# Project help: underscore template

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

I have a project that requires me to use underscore templating.

The app is suppose to get a recipe from an API and render it to the page.
If the user likes the recipe, they will be able to save it for later.

Could anyone help me out on how I would accomplish this? I'm not sure if the requests should be done from the client or server. Also, I'm not too sure how the returned data from the API (JSON) will be rendered to the page.

Below is the JSON object I got using postman on the API:

```
{"recipe": {
"publisher": "Closet Cooking",
"f2f_url": "http://food2fork.com/view/35171",
"ingredients": [
  "1/4 cup cooked shredded chicken, warm",
  "1 tablespoon hot sauce",
  "1/2 tablespoon mayo (optional)",
  "1 tablespoon carrot, grated",
  "1 tablespoon celery, sliced",
  "1 tablespoon green or red onion, sliced or diced",
  "1 tablespoon blue cheese, room temperature, crumbled",
  "1/2 cup cheddar cheese, room temperature, grated",
  "2 slices bread",
  "1 tablespoon butter, room temperature\\\n"
],
"source_url": "http://www.closetcooking.com/2011/08/buffalo-chicken-grilled-cheese-sandwich.html",
"recipe_id": "35171",
"image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/Buffalo2BChicken2BGrilled2BCheese2BSandwich2B5002B4983f2702fe4.jpg",
"social_rank": 100,
"publisher_url": "http://closetcooking.com",
"title": "Buffalo Chicken Grilled Cheese Sandwich"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perform the request to the 3rd party API on the server. Browsers enforce the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which prevents websites from making requests to servers that don't share the same "origin" (a combination of protocol, hostname and port number). This is an essential security feature that prevents sites from leaking private information or acting maliciously.

Once you've gotten the data from the API you need to render it into HTML markup. If you are running Javascript on your server, I would render it there, as it enables users who've disabled JS to still view the rendered information. Otherwise you should send the API data as a JSON string along with the page to reduce the number of server round-trips.

When you use underscore templates, you are writing markup with embedded Javascript that gets executed with respect to some context that you provide.

For instance, for the above API results, we could make a template that looks like so:

```
var compiledTemplate = _.template(
  '<div>' +
    '<h1><%= title %></h1>' +
    '<p>'
      'Published by ' +
      '<a href="<%= publisher_url %>">' +
        '<%= publisher %>' +
      '</a>' +
    '</p>' +
    '<h2>Ingredients</h2>' +
    '<ul><% _.each(ingredients, function(i) { %>' +
      '<li> <%= i %> </li>' +
    '<% }); %></ul>' +
  '</div>'
)
```

Then we could call it with the data above simply by passing the data as the context to the compiled template:

```
var renderedMarkup = compiledTemplate(data);
```

You would then send the rendered markup along to the user as the response to their request.

If you need more help writing underscore templates, check out the [official docs](http://underscorejs.org/#template) and [this guide](http://www.2ality.com/2012/06/underscore-templates.html).